# how I can use chef-google-sql for create a postgresql instance

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to use chef-google-sql for create a postgresql instance, but seems to be impossible. then, anyone uses this cookbook?. because seems no one use it.
If anyone just did it, please let me know how to make it

this was what I tried:

```rb
gsql_instance "sql-test-postgre" do
  action :create
  backend_type 'SECOND_GEN'
  database_version 'POSTGRESQL_9_6'
  instance_type 'CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE'
  settings({
    tier: 'db-n1-standard-1',
    ip_configuration: {
      authorized_networks: [
        {
          name: 'google dns server',
          value: '8.8.8.8/32'
        }
      ]
    }
  })
  region 'us-east1-b'
  project 'XXXX'
  credential 'mycred'
end
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Did you add the credentials section first to make sure you authenticate when using this?

Comment: by now, this cookbook hasn't support for postgresql, but, the people from google says they gonna add it in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your recipe is still under a testing phase. If you have a look at this [page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/chef-google-sql/tree/master/recipes), recipes starting with tests~ are not fully compatible with GCP resources yet.
This is your deployment [tests~instance.rb](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/chef-google-sql/blob/master/recipes/tests~instance.rb).